# Programming Other Atmel chips using Arduino

Tags: arduino-ide, arduino-nano, atmel

Is it possible to burn Arduino code on any other third party Atmel products using an another Arduino ? And if its possible then how ?

Comment: This is either unclear, or too broad.  Of course many things are possible, if someone builds the electrical interface and writes the program.  To have an answerable question you would have to ask about something specific: *which* target, and if you mean you want to load some random hex/binary/elf file, or if you mean you want to build an Arduino sketch using a port of the Arduino core to that target, and *then* load it using a classic ATmega Arduino as the programmer.

Comment: Build an sketch using port of Arduino core to that target and then use Arduino nano as an ISP.

Comment: What 3rd party Atmel products do you have in mind in particular? If you don't provide a list, then your question is already too broad. By the way, what is a "third-party Atmel" product, if it's Atmel, then it's not 3rd party, if it's 3rd party then it's not Atmel...

Comment: Please go the new link !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to burn Arduino code on any other third party Atmel products using an another Arduino ? And if its possible then how ?

Do you mean if the "Arduino as ISP" sketch and an Arduino would work to flash another Atmel AVR MCU? If so the answer is yes but I guess that you also want to generate code for the new MCU. In that case there is some work to be done before that is possible.

Start by reading about how to [install additional cores](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Cores) and the [guideline for a custom core](http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/CustomizeArduinoIDE). Then select an custom core to study. [Here](http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/ArduinoOnOtherAtmelChips) you will find the files you need to provide to support a new AVR based MCU.

Cheers!

Comment: There is some potential for confusion here. The ArduinoISP programmer is a dedicated programmer sold by Arduino, which is used by selecting **Tools > Programmer > ArduinoISP**. "Arduino as ISP" is the name of the programmer made by uploading the **File > Examples > 11.ArduinoISP** sketch to an Arduino and is selected via **Tools > Programmer > Arduino as ISP**. The two programmers are not interchangeable but it's easy to mistake one for the other because of the confusing sketch name.

Comment: Let me correct that to avoid any confusion.

Comment: Yup You kind off using Arduino ISP to program any other Atmel chip .Can you explain it point to point ? Mikael

Comment: No problems, I can google that for you; https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoISP

Comment: But if I want to program any other Microcontroller other than Atmega328 or Atmega168 Then ?

Comment: This is what happens when you ask a non-specific question and accept a response that doesn't answer what you wanted to know.  Ask better questions and you might get better answers.

Comment: Please go to this : http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/36238/programming-other-atmel-chipsexcluding-atmega-328-and-168 Sorry for the inconvenience faced ! Sorry !